# How do I package some of my webapp modules as an EAR file using Maven?

Tags: maven, web-applications, maven-3, war, ear

I'm using Maven 3.3.9I have a multi-module project whose parent POM looks something like the below

```
    <modules>
            <module>database</module>
            <module>jarprojectA</module>
            <module>jarprojectB</module>
            <module>webappA</module>
            <module>webappB</module>
            <module>jarprojectC</module>
            <module>webappC</module>
            <module>webappD</module>
            <module>webappE</module>
    </modules>
```

Is it possible, and if so how, to package some of my web app projects as an EAR file -- specifically modules "webappA," "webappB," "webappC," and "webappE"?  I'm using Wildfly 11 with Java 8 to deploy the applications.  I would like to be able to access each of the web applications in its own context path, however I would like to package them as a WAR file in hopes of cutting down on some duplicate classes that many of them share (I'm running out of MetaSpace when I deploy each of the web apps individually).

Comment: create separate module packaging `ear` add the modules you would like to package as dependencies..

Comment: @khmarbaise, you mean have anotehr module in my parent pom that packages the WAR modules I listed?

Comment: Yes...that's exactly the way...